# Pubspec.yaml resolving version failed in master channel but works in stable channel in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I still cannot figure this thing out. I got this error message when I do `flutter pub get`:

> Because no versions of flutter_i18n match >0.20.1 <0.21.0 and flutter_i18n 0.20.1 depends on intl ^0.16.0, flutter_i18n ^0.20.1 requires intl ^0.16.0.
> And because every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.17.0-nullsafety.2, flutter_i18n ^0.20.1 is incompatible with flutter_localizations from sdk.
> So, because my_app depends on both flutter_localizations any from sdk and flutter_i18n ^0.20.1, version solving failed.
> pub get failed (1; So, because my_app depends on both flutter_localizations any from sdk and flutter_i18n ^0.20.1, version solving failed.)

But I don't get this message in `stable` channel.
So far I always just switch back and forth. But I want to find the solution once and for all, because some tasks I need to do in `master` or `dev` channels.

Here is my `pubspec.yaml` file

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  # UI related packages
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  gradient_app_bar: ^0.1.3
  bubbled_navigation_bar: ^0.0.4
  titled_navigation_bar: ^3.6.0
  bubble_tab_indicator: ^0.1.4
  flutter_i18n: ^0.20.1
  gradient_widgets: ^0.5.0
  flutter_form_builder: ^3.14.0 # must be 3.14.0 because 3.14.1 will break
  keyboard_dismisser: ^1.0.2
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
  sliding_up_panel: ^1.0.2
  lazy_load_scrollview: ^1.1.0
  pull_to_refresh: ^1.6.2
  scroll_to_index: ^1.0.6
  date_time_format: ^1.0.0+4
  like_button: ^1.0.1

  # Login & App Store packages
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.4
  sign_in_with_apple: ^2.5.4
  purchases_flutter: ^1.4.0

  # Informing User / Loading
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.0.0
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.4
  shimmer: ^1.1.1
  flushbar: ^1.10.4
  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.3
  loading:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/leonzone/loading.git
      path: loading
      ref: 8f5a63f

  # I/O, Cache & Databases
  path: ^1.7.0
  path_provider: ^1.6.16
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.5
  flutter_cache_manager: ^1.4.2
  sembast: ^2.4.7+7
  sembast_cloud_firestore_type_adapters:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/tekartik/sembast_flutter_more.dart
      path: cloud_firestore_type_adapters
      ref: dart2
      version: '>=0.1.0'

  # Code structure, connectivity & internal services
  flutter_bloc: ^6.1.0
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
  http: ^0.12.1
  equatable: ^1.2.5
  simple_connectivity: ^0.1.1
  network_image_to_byte: ^0.0.1
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+11
  image: ^2.1.14
  package_info: ^0.4.1
  flutter_device_type: ^0.2.0
  audioplayers: 0.17.0
  url_launcher: ^5.7.8
  device_info: ^1.0.0
  in_app_review: ^1.0.3

  petitparser: ^3.0.2
  convert: ^2.1.1
  flutter_chips_input: ^1.9.3
  vector_math: ^2.0.8
  path_drawing: ^0.4.1
  matrix_gesture_detector: ^0.1.0

  # Social share packages
  social_share_plugin: ^0.3.1+1
  share: ^0.6.5+4

  # Firebase packages
  firebase_core: ^0.5.3
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.4
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.4
  firebase_storage: ^5.2.0
  firebase_database: ^4.4.0
  cloud_functions: ^0.7.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/i18n/
    - assets/audio/

  fonts:
    - family: Varela Round
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/VarelaRound-Regular.ttf
    - family: Font Awesome
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/FontAwesome-Regular.otf
```

And here is my `flutter doctor`:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.25.0-5.0.pre.141, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Anyone knows whats wrong here?

Once again, I don't have this problem in `stable` channel.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The dart and flutter teams are transitioning to [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety) feature. It is still in beta (that is why you get this error just with the beta channel). Not every package are already upgraded to null-sefety. You can fix this issue either by:

- asking the developer of the package to upgrade to null safety
- use a version of flutter which has not null-safety enabled
- use a beta version of the package with null-sefty enabled

Check also [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70433)