# Flutter intl version conflict

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I get this error:

> Because my_rents depends on flutter_localizations any from sdk which
> depends on intl 0.17.0-nullsafety.2, intl 0.17.0-nullsafety.2 is
> required. So, because my_rents depends on intl ^0.16.0, version
> solving failed. pub get failed (1; So, because my_rents depends on
> intl ^0.16.0, version solving failed.)

`my_rents` is the name of my app, it's not an specific package

If instead of

```
intl: ^0.16.1
```

I have

```
intl: 0.17.0-nullsafety.2
```

The error I get is

> Because firebase_auth >=0.18.0+1 <0.18.1 depends on firebase_auth_web
> ^0.3.0+1 and firebase_auth >=0.18.1 <=0.18.1+1 depends on
> firebase_auth_web ^0.3.1, firebase_auth >=0.18.0+1 <=0.18.1+1 requires
> firebase_auth_web ^0.3.0+1. And because firebase_auth >=0.18.1+2
> <0.18.2 depends on firebase_auth_web ^0.3.1+1, firebase_auth
>
> > =0.18.0+1 <0.18.2 requires firebase_auth_web ^0.3.0+1. And because firebase_auth >=0.18.2 <0.18.3 depends on firebase_auth_web ^0.3.1+2
> > and firebase_auth >=0.18.3+1 <0.18.4 depends on firebase_auth_web
> > ^0.3.2+1, firebase_auth >=0.18.0+1 <0.18.3-∞ or >=0.18.3+1 <0.18.4-∞
> > requires firebase_auth_web ^0.3.0+1. And because firebase_auth
> > =0.18.3 <=0.18.3 depends on firebase_auth_web ^0.3.2 and firebase_auth >=0.18.4 <=0.18.4 depends on firebase_auth_web ^0.3.2+2,
> > firebase_auth >=0.18.0+1 <=0.18.4 requires firebase_auth_web ^0.3.0+1.
> > And because firebase_auth ^0.18.4+1 depends on firebase_auth_web
> > ^0.3.2+3 which depends on intl ^0.16.1, firebase_auth ^0.18.0+1
> > requires intl ^0.16.1. So, because my_rents depends on both
> > firebase_auth ^0.18.0+1 and intl 0.17.0-nullsafety.2, version solving
> > failed. pub get failed (1; So, because my_rents depends on both
> > firebase_auth ^0.18.0+1 and intl 0.17.0-nullsafety.2, version solving
> > failed.)

Comment: The easiest way is to remove version specification for the plugins raising conflicts.

`intl:`

Comment: without anything you mean? What's the difference from "any"?

Comment: I'm not sure if they are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dart and flutter teams are transitioning to [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety) feature. It is still in beta (that is why you get this error just with the beta channel). Not every package are already upgraded to null-sefety. You can fix this issue either by:

- asking the developer of the package to upgrade to null safety
- use a version of flutter which has not null-safety enabled
- use a beta version of the package with null-sefty enabled
  [Check also this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70433)

Original answer: [Pubspec.yaml resolving version failed in master channel but works in stable channel in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65230859/pubspec-yaml-resolving-version-failed-in-master-channel-but-works-in-stable-chan)

For now easiest solution is:

```
flutter channel stable

flutter upgrade
```

Comment: Already updated with the latest flutter version but still facing the same issue.

Comment: as I mentioned this rely on each package and we cannot be sure what's going on. You need to find package by package which one is creating this conflict and apply those steps

Comment: Yes Dani, you are right. I have checked all the packages dependency and some packages need old version of `intl` and some are happy with latest `intl` package version. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the issue by settings the 'any' to resolve issue

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65971167/14950155

Intl: any

Comment: but how do I know the versions I have running? I think if I have too many "any"s it would be a bit difficult to find any issue, specially if I have to report them in their github repos

Comment: also I can't have new versions every time I reinstall my packages

Comment: Null Safety exception and issue cause only in beta channel... Still beta channel used for ensuring the web.

Comment: `any` could not solve the issue. Issue is still persist.